# What do I do when a question was closed for "needing clarity", but doesn't state what needs clarification?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I recently [asked a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1624524/why-do-tvs-have-different-input-lags-with-computers-than-they-do-with-other-devi) that was closed about 1 minute later due to it needing "details or clarity".

However, there weren't any comments in the closure remarks, and there were no comments or answers on the question itself.

I've since tried to make edits to the question to help clarify what it is I am asking for, with a few more details on what I *think* was missing for someone to provide an answer, but I'm not really sure what I should be doing.

On the closure notes, it suggests editing the original or posting an updated question.

Will editing the question make a difference in getting it reopened, or should I remake another question with the same information?

Answer (score 2):

It's been reopened judging by as of now. There are also comments stating what you can do to improve it. I suggest you take those comments and improve your question on those criticisms.